# changing ToggleButton colors from react-bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a group of ToggleButtons on my application whose background colors I would like to change. Currently my code gives all the buttons a gradient of <.untoggled-button> and the unselected buttons have that gradient with an added blue film. I have two problems: I want to remove the blue film on the untoggled buttons and I need to access the toggled button to change it's styling. <.toggled-button> is just a placeholder that doesn't do anything right now.

I'm wondering how to access the **unchecked** and **checked** versions of the ToggleButtons in my css, as to override the default bootstrap styling!

the jsx:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup className="view" type="radio" name="options" defaultValue={2}>
        <ToggleButton value={1} className="untoggled-button" > title</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={2} className="untoggled-button"> title</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={3} className="untoggled-button"> title</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

the css (this is very incorrect, but I'm hoping to be able to style both unchecked and checked buttons):

```
.untoggled-button{
  background-image: some gradient !important;
}
.toggled-button {
  background-image: another gradient !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi sun, can you include the code for this component you are talking about?

Comment: @MarioPerez done!! not sure how helpful it is, but this is my basic logic (I removed handlers to make it easier to read)

Comment: @sun have you tried adding `!important` to your background-image?

Comment: @John yup! sorry, I will edit my question to elaborate, but what my current code does is the selected button has the gradient of <.untoggled-button> and the unselected buttons have that same gradient with an added blue film. I'm unsure how to access the toggled button styling (.toggled-button) is just a placeholder, and how to remove the default blue film.

Comment: @sun, I think bootstrap adds the class `collapsed` so possibly try something like `.collapsed {background-image: Your Gradient;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting the background color to transparent and adding a .active class seems to have worked!

```
.untoggled-button{
  background-image: some gradient !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
. untoggled-button.active {
  background-image: another gradient !important;
}
```